# How can i use with proxy?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I'm new at anglesharp. I tried the proxy change at the documentation but it didnt work. 
Now i'm using this, it works well with webclient but it isnt working with AngleSharp.

The code i'm trying is ;

```csharp
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "myProxy", "myPort"), false),
                PreAuthenticate = true,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            };
            var config = Configuration.Default.WithJs().WithCookies().WithDefaultLoader().With(handler);

            //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);     
            var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
            Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
```

I'm not getting any error, proxy is not working thats it. I'm getting my original ip not the proxys.
But with WebClient it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add something (`handler`, i.e., a `HttpClientHandler` instance) to AngleSharp's configuration - something that will not be used by anything in AngleSharp.

First of all AngleSharp's internal HTTP client is only a default client. For compatibility reasons AngleSharp cannot ship with `HttpClient` instead if  uses `HttpWebRequest`. This also allows you setting a proxy.

Now if you want to use your code I suggest you use AngleSharp.Io (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp.Io or https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Io). It's quite simple and straight forward:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(String.Format("{0}:{1}", "myProxy", "myPort"), false),
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
};
var config = Configuration.Default
    .WithRequesters(handler)
    .WithDefaultLoader()
    .WithJs()
    .WithTemporaryCookies()
    .WithDefaultLoader();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);     
var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml)
```

Only `.WithRequesters(handler)` has been added. This adds the requesters from AngleSharp.Io. By providing `handler` we can configure the `HttpClient`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Florian it worked perfectly and i'm sure i'll help your project somehow :)